# How do you make this colour displacement type image

Tags: color, gradient

I found this on itunes radio and want to know how this was achieved like how the triangle was made.

[image]

I have come up with this so far in photoshop

[image]

Comment: "Masks" would be the short answer. However, we do not know what you have tried, and what software you have access to...

Comment: Nice attempt so far John. I think you just need to play about with the brightness of the layers as they are very similar.

Comment: Is your difficulty in making a triangular selection / mask, or in achieving the specific color shift effect in the first image?

Answer (score 1):

The photo has been realigned in the triangle shapes to create greater contrast. Then combinations of colour/gradient overlays, adjustment layers and blend modes have been applied in Photoshop. Experiment with these/research lomography effects

Comment: -1: This answer uses a lot of fancy jargon, but actually says almost nothing beyond "it was done in Photoshop" (which might not even be true; there's plenty of other programs you could do this in, including vector graphics editors like Illustrator).

Comment: Of course there are many software solutions available, if you really wanted to you could hack the JPEG code into creating the effects. All I can do is offer advise on how I would create the piece. Apologies if you find overlays and adjustment layers too confusing.

Comment: I'm honestly shocked you've said 'fancy jargon' when you then offer Illustrator as an alternate solution. Although possible, it's completely the wrong approach for a piece like this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could create this effect, and several programs you could do this in.  In all cases, the basic idea is:

- Start with a base image — in this case, a sunset over the sea.
- Make several copies of the base image — here, there seem to be four copies.  Resize and/or move the copies so that they don't match exactly.
- Create a triangular shape, and make several (here, three) copies of it.  The triangle here seems to be just a simple equilateral triangle standing on one corner, but you could use some other shape, too.  Scale the copies so that they form the nice nested arrangement seen in the image.
- Set the scaled triangles as mask / clip shapes on the upper copies of the base image, so that only the part of the image within the triangle is visible.
- Optionally, tweak the colors, contrast and lightness of each copy of the base image.  However, you may find that just the intrinsic color variations between different parts of the image are enough to produce the desired effect.

Since Photoshop has already been suggested as one program you could do this in, let me instead show how to do it in [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/), a free vector graphics editor:

1. First, we need a base image.  I picked a random snapshot I took with my cell phone while sailing.  It's not quite as pretty and pink as the sunset in your image above (at least not without some serious color tweaking), but it'll do for an example:

   [image: Step 1: Base image]
2. Next, we'll open up Inkscape and, create a triangle using the polygon / star tool, and we make some copies of it and scale them.  Note how the outer copies extend outside the page area:

   [image: Step 2a: Create a triangle]
   [image: Step 2b: Make copies of the triangle]
3. Next, we'll import the base photo into Inkscape and scale it so that it covers the whole image.  This'll be our base layer:

   [image: Step 3: Import the base photo]
4. Next, we copy the photo, move and rescale it so that it mostly shows the waves.  Then we select the scaled copy and the outermost triangle, and use the *Object → Clip → Set* tool to clip the image within the triangle:

   [image: Step 4a: Copy and scale the base image]
   [image: Step 4b: Clip the scaled copy to the outer triangle]
5. Then we repeat the process for the middle triangle:

   [image: Step 5a: Copy and scale the base image again]
   [image: Step 5b: Clip the new scaled copy to the middle triangle]
6. ...and finally for the innermost triangle:

   [image: Step 6a: Make yet another scaled copy of the base image]
   [image: Step 6b: ...and clip it to the inner triangle]
7. As a finishing touch, let's add some text on top:

   [image: Step 7: Final image with text]

We could also tweak the colors in the images using filters, or by editing the images in a raster graphics editor.  However, as shown by the examples above, that's not really necessary for producing this effect — just moving and scaling the images is enough.